# Set the Video Codec to H.264 when using an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput instance? Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, avcapturemoviefileoutput

Need help setting the video codec to H.264 when using an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput instance.

Looking at the Apple Docs I see that they support a struct of type AVVideoCodecType, however, I'm not seeing this in the Xamarin.iOS Docs.

Help would be much appreciated as I don't want to have to rewrite the Video Capture logic to use AVAssetWriter.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/AVFoundation.AVVideoCodecType/

Comment: I didn’t downvote you.  I did provide you with a pointer to an answer.  And please learn to be civil.

Comment: The AVVideoCodecType Is an enum, your implying that its value can be used to set the CodecType of the AVCaptureMovieFileOutput. However, there's no property on the object that allows it. @Jason

Comment: @Jason thanks for not giving me the absolute answer... Not being sarcastic. Led me to the solution, which I was already on the correct path just missing a piece to the puzzle.

Comment: cool, you should post the answer so others can see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found the solution and here it is for those who come after me.

**Step 1:** Create a AVCaptureMovieFileOutput instance.

```
var output = new AVCaptureMovieFileOutput();
```

**Step 2:** Create a NSDictionary where you list the keys and values of the Movie's Output settings you want.

```
var outputSettings = new NSDictionary(AVVideoCodecType.H264, AVVideo.CodecKey);
```

**Step 3:** Set the output Settings

```
output.SetOutputSettings(outputSettings, output.ConnectionFromMediaType(AVMediaType.Video))
```

The trick here is to call ConnectionFromMediaType Method passing in the MediaType on your AVCaptureMovieFileOutput instance which returns an AVCaptureConnection.

Comment: NSDictionary takes the key first, and the value second (at least when using Xamarin iOS SDK 12). Your code seems to be putting the value first and the key second. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsdictionary?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

Comment: I modified the code into this and got it working when testing on an iphone 12:

// Use the H.264 codec aka avc1 to encode the video.
var availableCodec = videoOutput.AvailableVideoCodecTypes.SingleOrDefault(v => v.ToString().Equals("avc1", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
if(availableCodec != null)
{
 var outputConnection = videoOutput.ConnectionFromMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
    var outputSettings = new NSDictionary(AVVideo.CodecKey, availableCodec);
    videoOutput.SetOutputSettings(outputSettings, outputConnection);
}

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to get this to work in Xamarin.iOS:

```
var videoOutput = new AVCaptureMovieFileOutput();
var outputSettings = new NSDictionary(AVVideo.CodecKey, AVVideo.CodecH264);

videoOutput.SetOutputSettings(outputSettings, videoOutput.Connections[0]);
```